# How to deal with "The message cannot be deserialized into MessageContract type" in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

After sending a request to add a new affiliate user in the DB by clicking on the Create button, I am getting "The message cannot be deserialized into MessageContract type FXM.Ordering.WS.Contract.BoCreateAffiliateRequest since it does not have a default (parameterless) constructor."

[screenshot of UI and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRcmO.png)

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateAffiliate(NewAffiliateViewModel newAffiliateViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = BackOfficeServices.BoAddAffiliateUser(newAffiliateViewModel);
                //SystemServices.ResendEmail(userId);
                return Json("success");

                //return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

My ajax requests

```
@*<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    // document.ready function
    $(function () {
        refreshGroups();
        refreshEmployees();
        // selector has to be . for a class name and # for an ID
        $('#create-affiliate-button').click(function (e) {
            //e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from reloading page
            console.log("blahblahblah");
            //alert("hiii");

            var b = $("form").serialize();
            //var a = $("form").serializeArray();
            console.log("formvalues", b);

            $.ajax({
                @*url: "@Url.Action("CreateAffiliate", "AjaxUI")",*@
                url: "/en/AjaxUI/CreateAffiliate",
                type: "POST",
            //dataType: "json",
            data: b,
               
            

                //error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                //    failMessage();
                //}
            });
        });
    });



    function refreshGroups() {
        var pltf = "MT4_LIVE";
        var out = $('#MT4Group');
        if (pltf != null && pltf !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/' + window.currentLangCulture + '/BOLiveForms/GetPlatformGroupByFilter',
                data: {
                    platform: pltf, currency: "", withId : true
                },
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    populateDropDown(out, data);
                    //$('#recomandedGroup').show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            out.empty();
            out.append($('<option></option>').val('').html(window.defaultSelection));
        }
    }

    //function urlResult() {
    //    return "/" + window.langlang + "/AjaxUI/CreateAffiliate";
    //}


    function refreshEmployees() {
        //debugger;
        //var pltf = "MT4_LIVE";
        var out = $('#Employee');
        //if (pltf != null && pltf !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/en/BOEmployeeAjax/GetEmployeesExcept",
                data: {
                    emplId : 0
                    //platform: pltf, currency: "", withId: true
                },
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#tpLoader').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //populateDropDown(out, data);
                    //$('#recomandedGroup').show();
                    //debugger;
                    for(var value of data)
                    out.append($('<option>' + value.text + '</option>').val(value.id))

                }
            });
```

My view model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FXM.BO.ViewModels
{
    public class NewAffiliateViewModel
    {
        public NewAffiliateViewModel()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AffiliateName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }


        public int Employee { get; set; }


        public int MT4Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far is googling the issue and tried to add a parameterless controller but I am not sure if it was done correctly as it didn't solve the problem. What am I missing?

My Startup.cs code:

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Wcf;
using FXM.Ordering.WS.Core.DependencyManagement;
using FXM.Ordering.WS.Reporting;
using FXM.Ordering.WS.Utils;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(FXM.Ordering.WS.Startup))]

namespace FXM.Ordering.WS
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {                                               
            IContainer container = AutofacContainerBuilder.BuildContainer();            
            AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to add the code you provided.

Comment: The error says that `BoCreateAffiliateReques` `does not have a default (parameterless) constructor`. Where is that class? It *must* have a default constructor

Comment: Remove `catch (Exception e) {  throw e; }`. It does nothing more than truncate the exception's stack trace. Use `catch { throw;}` if you want to have a placeholder for a breakpoint. It looks like you're trying to call a SOAP service using a class that's missing a constructor. The exception's call stack would show you which method calls led to the exception but right now only shows where `throw ex` was called

Comment: On the other hand, a `FaultException` is typically thrown by a WCF *server* when something goes wrong. Have you checked the web service's logs? And. ....  wait ...... A controller with 2901 lines??????? This needs some *serious* refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a container for injection. If so, then it's probably not registered. Take IServiceCollection inside Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

This adds all controllers to the container. Check your configuration and make sure it's registered

Comment: I uploaded my Startup.cs code as EDIT-1. I am not sure how to add the code you provided.
I also don't know how to check my configuration to make sure it's registered.

Comment: The error complains about the class constructor, not service registration.